# Trying to remove a section of the code that appends rows together

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to modify the section of this code that appends rows, so that it just overwrites. Everything I try breaks the whole thing. The section im trying to remove is between ('append all other columns if different) and   (' now delete the duplicate row)

```
Sub Consolidate()

    Worksheets("1").Activate
    
    Columns("H:BV").EntireColumn.Delete
    
    Dim last_row As Long
        Dim row As Long
        Dim s As Worksheet
        Dim col As Integer
    
    Set s = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1") ' use this line to process a specific sheet
    
    last_row = s.Cells(s.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row 'find the last row with data
    
        For row = last_row To 3 Step -1
            If s.Cells(row, "D").Value = s.Cells(row - 1, "D").Value Then
                ' found a match in column d
                
                ' add column F
                s.Cells(row - 1, "F").Value = s.Cells(row - 1, "F").Value + s.Cells(row, "F").Value
                
                ' add column G
                s.Cells(row - 1, "G").Value = s.Cells(row - 1, "G").Value + s.Cells(row, "G").Value
               
                'append all other columns if different
                For col = 1 To 5
                    If Not s.Cells(row, col).Value = s.Cells(row - 1, col).Value Then
                      s.Cells(row - 1, col).Value = s.Cells(row - 1, col).Value & " " & s.Cells(row, col).Value
                    End If
                Next
                
                ' now delete the duplicate row
                s.Rows(row).Delete
            End If
        Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `s.Cells(row - 1, col).Value = s.Cells(row, col).Value` should do it

Comment: PS you have asked a bunch of questions, but have only accepted one of the answers provided.  Please consider reviewing your posts and accepting any answers which were helpful.  Folks eventually stop responding if you do not provide any feedback...